# Mod a Wordpress Function to have 10 iteration per times

Tags: wordpress, function

Im tryng to mod this function to make an update more powerful.

What im tryng to do is to mod this function:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'cron_revise_changed_listings' );

    function cron_revise_changed_listings() {

    global $wpdb;

    if ( !isset( $_REQUEST['wplister_revise_all'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $limit = isset( $_REQUEST['revise_limit'] ) ? intval( $_REQUEST['revise_limit'] ) : 10;

    $listings = $wpdb->get_results("
            SELECT id, account_id
         FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ebay_auctions
         WHERE status = 'changed'
         ORDER BY id DESC
         LIMIT {$limit}", ARRAY_A );

    if ( empty( $listings ) ) {
        die( json_encode( array( 'revised' => 0 ) ) );
    }

    $lm = new ListingsModel();

    $revised = 0;
    $last_account_id = false;
    foreach ( $listings as $listing ) {
        if ( $last_account_id != $listing['account_id'] ) {
            $last_account_id = $listing['account_id'];
            WPLE()->initEC( $listing['account_id'] );
        }
        $lm->reviseItem( $listing['id'], WPLE()->EC->session );
        $revised++;
    }

    WPLE()->EC->closeEbay();
    die( json_encode( array( 'revised' => $revised ) ) );
}
```

What i need to obtain is to repeat cycle for each, but with a step of 10 items per time so for revise 100 items it need only to do 10 cicles and not 100...someone have any ideas?

Comment: What does repet cicle mean?

Comment: try toexplain better. For each repeat cicle, in this way for 100 items only need 10 for each cicle...

Comment: By cicle you mean cycle

Comment: maybe i used wrong "cicle" sorry but im italian!

Comment: what i need is to revise for each...if you see it revise an array...but one revision per time...i wanna make this function modify for revise 10 items per time until all items of the $listings arrays are revised